# How I can write at a location FFFF0H in assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86-16

I want to write a `jmp` instruction at the location *FFFF0H* and with destination *F8000H*.

After that, I want to place the code below at *F8000H*, so that upon execution from *FFFF0H* the control will be transferred, through the jump above, to it.

```
.MODEL SMALL
.8086

.STACK

.DATA

.CODE

.STARTUP

LL:
  MOV AL, 1H

IO_LOOP:
  OUT 0EH, AL
  SHL AL, 1

  ;Delay
  MOV CX, 0FFFFH
DLOOP:
  NOP
 LOOP DLOOP

 ;Start all over again
 CMP AL, 00H
JE  LL

 ;Get back to IO cycle
JMP IO_LOOP

END
```

Comment: I completely rephrased your messy question. You have to absolutely check if my interpretation was correct and if the updated question is still a reflection of your needs.  Above my avatar, you can see an "Edited XX ago" link, click it to access the revision history and eventually rollback to the original question. On the left corner you can further edit my work if necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Note**

The address range *0F0000h*-*0FFFFFh* is read only.
The true story is that it is set read-only by the firmware upon startup after the shadow copy of the BIOS has been made, so that an access doesn't have to go all the way down to the PCH, that by default reroute it at the standard address range *FFFF_0000H*-*FFFF_FFFFH*.

So those address range is either mapped to a read-only DRAM area or to a Flash ROM that ignores write requests until programmed.

If you are writing a firmware, then surely the build-chain supports the creation of sections that can be placed anywhere in the ROM.
Explaining how to use such tool is beyond the scope of this answer and this site.

---

It seems you are writing a normal DOS executable though, please note that the solution below will **not** work.
Hence-on I will simply assume that you want to move a piece of code from *A* to *B*.

We need:

1. Some code to move data between two memory region.
   This can be done in many ways, the fastest to code, yet slowest (for small blocks) is the use of `rep movsb` that copy `cx` bytes from `ds:si` to `es:di`.
2. A way to tell the length of a piece of code.
   We can put two labels, say *S* and *E*, respectively at the start and at the end of the piece of code. This way the expression *E*-*S* gives the difference, in bytes, between the two labels, i.e. the length of the code.

Here a possible implementation:

```
.MODEL SMALL
.8086

.STACK

.DATA

.CODE

.STARTUP

 ;Set up ES
 mov ax, 0f000h
 mov es, ax

 ;Move the first routine 

 mov si, OFFSET __ROUTINE_1__START__                   ;DS:SI = Start of the routine to copy
 mov di, 8000h                                         ;ES:DI = 0f000h:8000h = 0f8000h
 mov cx,  __ROUTINE_1__END__ - __ROUTINE_1__START__    ;CX = Length of the routine to copy
 rep movsb

 ;Copy the jump

 mov si, OFFSET __ROUTINE_2__START__
 mov di, 0fff0h                                        ;ES:DI = 0f000h:0fff0h = 0ffff0h
 mov cx,  5                                            ;Absolute far jump is 5 bytes
 rep movsb


 ;DO SOMETHING HERE

 ;
 ; ROUTINE TO MOVE
 ;

__ROUTINE_1__START__:
LL:
  MOV AL, 1H

IO_LOOP:
  OUT 0EH, AL
  SHL AL, 1

  ;Delay
  MOV CX, 0FFFFH
DLOOP:
  NOP
 LOOP DLOOP

 ;Start all over again
 CMP AL, 00H
JE  LL

 ;Get back to IO cycle
JMP IO_LOOP

__ROUTINE_1__END__:

__ROUTINE_2__START__:
 jmp FAR 0f000h:8000h                 ;TODO: Adjust the syntax for the assembler dialect

END
```

As I said, this solution won't work for the address range you picked up, unless you are working in a special context. 
I also assumed you know how segmentation works.

I didn't create the far `jmp` directly by storing the machine code with `mov`-immediate stores; instead I let the assembler create the machine code and then I copied it.
It is less efficient but lets you change the code without much trouble.